# How to fix error in DB Browser where foreign key instruction causing empty table?

Tags: database, sqlite, foreign-keys, db-browser-sqlite

Trying to build tables for a project in DB Browser and one of my tables is being created without any attribute columns, totally empty.

I've determined through trial, that the offending instruction is one of the foreign key assignments (specifically the one assigning `EMPLOYEE.emp_years` as a foreign key reference to `RAISE.emp_years`). By commenting out this line, the table builds completely, with all attribute columns. But I need this line.

```
CREATE TABLE PAYRATE (
rai_bump    DECIMAL (2, 2) NOT NULL,
bas_basepay DECIMAL (2, 2) NOT NULL,
pay_rate    DECIMAL (2, 2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(rai_bump, bas_basepay)
);

CREATE TABLE BASEPAY (
emp_agerange    CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
bas_basepay     DECIMAL (2, 2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(emp_agerange),
FOREIGN KEY(bas_basepay) REFERENCES PAYRATE(bas_basepay)
);


CREATE TABLE RAISE (
emp_years   INTEGER NOT NULL,
rai_bump    DECIMAL (2, 2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(emp_years),
FOREIGN KEY(rai_bump) REFERENCES PAYRATE(rai_bump)
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
emp_num         INTEGER NOT NULL,
emp_fname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
emp_lname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
emp_years       INTEGER NOT NULL,
emp_agerange    CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(emp_num),
FOREIGN KEY(emp_years) REFERENCES RAISE(emp_years), /* <-- offender */
FOREIGN KEY(emp_agerange) REFERENCES BASEPAY(emp_agerange)
);
```

The Employee table should have the 5 attributes, `emp_num`, `emp_fname`, `emp_lname`, `emp_years`, and `emp_agerange`. When I run my code without the offending line above, that is what I get, but with the line, the employee table is created but has no columns at all. I get no error messages. It says it runs successfully both with and without the offending line.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the cause. After having trouble while troubleshooting, getting errors any time I referred to the RAISE table, I got syntax errors. I got an inkling and looked up the word. Sure enough, RAISE if a reserved word in SQLite. It let me create a table with the name, but wouldn't let me refer to it because it thought I was referencing the RAISE function.

Comment: Raise is a keyword but not a reserved word. Your code works fine in SQLite Studio 3.2.1. So the problem must be a bug of DB Browser.